# Angularjs Button loading state and disabled when calling server rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my angular application, I have some buttons that call REST services.

Sometimes, the Rest Service takes a long time to reply. To prevent the user to click once before receiving the service answer, I would like to **disable** the button and change his value to '**loading...**'

I want to do the same, only for all buttons whose value is equal to '**Search**' or  '**Relaunch**'

Exemple:
[image]

Code :

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="relaunch()" ng-value="Relaunch"/>

$scope.relaunch= function(){
    RelaunchService.relaunch().then(function(data){
       // server response
      })
};
```

For this, I want to create one directive. But I do not know how to do it :-(

PS: Note that the user can click on several different buttons at the same time.

Comment: Please, show us your code.

Comment: @AlessioCantarella code added

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Syntax is

```
<INPUT
 ng-disabled="expression">
  ...
</INPUT>
```

So in  your case you can do it as

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" ng-disabled="btnDisabled"  ng-click="relaunch()" ng-value="Relaunch"/>
 $scope.btnDisabled=false;
 $scope.relaunch= function(){
     $scope.btnDisabled=true;
     RelaunchService.relaunch().then(function(data){
       // server response

     }).finally(function(){
         $scope.btnDisabled=false;
     })
 };
```

Comment: You probably better have to use `finally()` instead of `then()` to re-enable button

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to use only one directive. because I have a lot of button so a lot of code to modify in this case